# How to change media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have found some code but want to change the CSS to show only two boxes across the page at one time.

Can some explain to me how to change the media queries css to show only two boxes when you change the screen size.

i have made a fiddle to show my working .

http://jsfiddle.net/pbVLe/

```
#upload-container-two {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
#upload-container-two ul {
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
#upload-container-two ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
  width: 93%;
}

#upload-container-two ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#upload-container-two ul li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13px;
  display: none;
}
#upload-container-two ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
#upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+0) {
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 5.85%;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #upload-container-two ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 42.08%;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(1n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  #upload-container-two ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 27.73%;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 34.29%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+3) {
    margin-left: 68.59%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  #upload-container-two ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
    width: 20.8%;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li span {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-left: 25.96%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+3) {
    margin-left: 51.93%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
  #upload-container-two ul li:nth-child(2n+4) {
    margin-left: 77.89%;
    margin-bottom: 3.85%;
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand, you don't want margin ?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to display 2 columns rather than 4?

Answer (score 0):

Add two container to play width the float:none. Don't forget your clear:both class.

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/fJvnw)

```
<div id="main">

<div class="col">
  <ul>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>    
  </ul>

    <ul>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>    
  </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div> 

  <div class="col">
    <ul>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>    
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>
    <li>coucou</li>    
  </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div> 

<div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```